# How to chain my promises - Fetch not returning desired results

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

## Fetch Promises Not Working For Me

I am a newbie when it comes to using Javascript Promises. In my current project, I believe Promises are a candidate for the task I am trying to achieve. The project is simple, it is an online form to submit a quote (or estimate) to a customer.

I am working on the page that will display a Quote that has already been submitted - ( view-quote.html )

Here is the task broken down:

- Given a quote_id (url param), I want to query the QUOTES table.
- In those results are a customer id.
- Finally, I want to query the ITEMS table using the quote_id.

## Synchronous or Asynchronous ?

Since one query depends upon another, I thought I could use the Fetch statement, which is "then-able".

I THINK I am supposed to use asynchronous code to achieve this task, right? I'm not sure though. Maybe traditional "callbacks" are what I need?

#### My Current Non-Working Code...

Here is as far as I got. I pieced this together by following tips and tutorials I found on Stack's site.

```sh
var getQuote = function() {
   fetch(apiQuoteUrl+"GL555")  // for testing, I hardcoded a quote num
  .then(status)
  .then(json)
  .then(function(data) {
    // WORKS - this DOES return me the client id
    //alert(data[0].client_id);
    gClient_id = data[0].client_id; // move to global var
  }).catch(function(error) {
    console.log('Request failed', error);
  });
};


// This function takes one parameter, the client id
// which comes from the fetch call above.
var getClient = function(clientId) {
   fetch()
  .then(status)
  .then(json)
  .then(function(data) {
      // TO BE DETERMINED, NOT SURE
      // WHAT TO PUT HERE

  }).catch(function(error) {
    console.log('Request failed', error);
  });
};

var getItems = function() {
   fetch()
  .then(status)
  .then(json)
  .then(function(data) {
      // TO BE DETERMINED, NOT SURE
      // WHAT TO PUT HERE
  }).catch(function(error) {
    console.log('Request failed', error);
  });
};



function status(response) {
  if (response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300) {
    return Promise.resolve(response)
  } else {
    return Promise.reject(new Error(response.statusText))
  }
}

function json(response) {
  return response.json()
}
```

#### What to do next?

Ok, I have the framework put in place. But, I don't know to proceed. I have followed dozens of tutorials on Fetch and Promises, but they don't quite fit my needs, therefore, I am stil stuck.

#### Right Track?

So I am now concerned that I am making this harder than it needs to be. Am I even on the right track by using promises?

Thank you for looking. Your advice/code help is really appreciated.

John

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> They weren't working for me either!

Hello! I believe I recently had the same problem as you: "Chaining Promises"

A quick search brought me [here](https://javascript.info/promise-chaining), and I was able to resolve my problems.

The basics are, you need to return a value from a promise in order to `.then()` it.

So in the case of `fetch()` try something like this

```
var getQuote = function() {
  fetch(apiQuoteUrl + "GL555")
    .then(status => return status.json())
    .then(data => {
      alert(data[0].client_id);
      gClient_id = data[0].client_id;
    }).catch(error => {
      console.log('Request failed', error);
    });
};
```